# Customize execution of Junit test suite in modules

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I have a set of Junit 4 test classes which I want to run in multiple modules with differing BeforeClass, AfterClass, Before and After hooks. With `@Rule` injections I get only wrapping of test methods, but no BeforeClass and AfterClass behaviour.

Also I don't want to do this with a test runner, since then I have fixed the test runner to be used for a large set of tests.

Subclassing each test class in the target modules and applying the customizations there doesn't seem to be a good solution.

The best would be to just declared something like this in the target modules

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  investmentTests.class,
  catalogTests.class,
  markerTests.class 
})
public class AllTests {
    // why on earth I need this class, I have no idea! 
}
```

and have some environmental hooks to apply the before/after code.

Have you come across a solution for this problem?

Comment: JUnit 4.9 will have class-level rules.

Comment: do you need a class-level Rule as NamshubWriter commented?

Comment: The class level rule seems to be just what I need. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NamshubWriter commented, **org.junit.ClassRule** is found in JUnit4.9. `@ClassRule` instead of `@Rule`; `TestRule` instead of `MethodRule`.

See the sample:

```
public static class CustomCounter extends TestRule {
    public int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {                
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                count++;
                base.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }       
}

public static class ExampleTestWithCustomClassRule {
    @ClassRule
    public static CustomCounter counter= new CustomCounter();

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        assertEquals(1, counter.count);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        assertEquals(1, counter.count);
    }
}
```